# How do I hook an AngularJS directive into two different projects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-module

I am searching for a tutorial on specifically this, but don't seem to find it, so maybe its something I missed:

If I declare a module, saved as myproject.js

```
var myProject = angular.module('myProject',[]);
```

Later I add a directive, saved as domchanger.directive.js

```
myProject.directive('domchanger', function (){});
```

But now, I have a new project, saved as newproject.js

```
var newProject = angular.module('newProject', []);
```

But if I try to add domchanger, its hooked into myProject.

surely I shouldn't have to save a whole version with the myProject changed to newProject?

I'm sure I've seen somehow where I would somehow do something to the directive to make it generic, so it can be used on any module. Most online documentation seems to skip this step, or not even get to it.

What do I need to do, to allow domchanger.directive.js to be plug and play for newProject?

EDIT: as per request for simplified non working code

```
var myProject = angular.module('myProject', []);


myProject.controller('projectControl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.Test = "hello";

}]);

myProject.directive('projectDirective', function () {

});

var newProject = angular.module('newProject', ['projectControl', 
'projectDirective']);
```

This gives me a

Failed to instantiate module newProject due to:
Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable

If that helps..

Comment: Good to have separate module for directive `domchanger.directive.js`, then you can inject the directive module with multiple project wherever you want.

Comment: I think these words are why I couldn't get this, Without that leap of faith about directives, modules and injection, its not really clear and not one tute spells it out clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what your "domchanger.directive.js" look like...

```
    var app = angular.module("myDirective", []);
app.directive("testDirective", function() {
//...
});
app.controller('testController',function($scope){
//...
});
```

this plug n'play (injectable module) can be called in your projects like...

```
 var app = angular.module("myProject", ["myDirective"]);
```

or
     var app = angular.module("newProject", ["myDirective"]);

Hope this is what you are looking for...

Comment: yet you've declared is as app.directive, what if the new project is 

var diffApp = angular.module("myProject", ["myDirective"]); , surely myDirective won't work as its app.directive, not diffApp.directive?

Comment: diffApp.directive should work... I have used injectable module's controllers and filters... this should work with directives also... if you can update your question with minimal code which doesn't work under this scenario... I will try to address it (as will many potential others)

Comment: @alqbalRaj, I updated the question with cut-down code, tested it to see the error.

Comment: Ok, Spotted it.. You don't reference the directive by name, you reference the module the directive is attached to. 

Is it common practice to create a whole module for all your libraries and attach them?